# Is there such phrase as "what more"?

Tags: comparisons

In sentences that I want to emphasize the ability of a person to do a certain task at a greater degree than another person, will it make sense to use "what more"?

1. If Canelo can do that to Khan, *what more* can Golovkin?
2. John, a novice swimmer, was able to finish the race. *What more* if it were Michael Phelps who competed?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

1. If Canelo can do that to Khan, imagine what Golovkin can do.
2. Imagine if Michael Phelps had competed.

'what more' : 
I've apologized a thousand times - what more can I say?

Answer (score 1):

For your intended purpose, it's better to use "**what's more**", defined by [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/what%27s+more)

> the next fact is at least as important or even more important.
>
> *"Military action will hurt ordinary people, and what's more, it won't solve the problem."*

I hope this helps. *What more* would you like to know?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Let alone" or "not to mention".

You sound like a Malaysian. "What more" sounds like a direct translation from "apa lagi".

Comment: Please show how these phrases can be used to answer the question.  As it stands, substituting "let alone" would not fit the original syntax.  Do take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].